# Is the following generalization of the Caratheodory theorem true?

Tags: convex-polytopes, convex-geometry

The colorful Carathéodory theorem (Bárány, 1982) considers $d+1$ "colors" $X_1,\ldots,X_{d+1}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$, and a point $x$ in the convex hull of each color ($x\in \text{conv}(X_i)$ for each $i\in[d+1]$). It says that there exists a set of $d+1$ points of distinct colors, such that $x$ is in their convex hull.

Suppose that, instead of a single point $x$, there are $d+1$ points $x_1\in \text{conv}(X_1),\ldots,x_{d+1}\in \text{conv}(X_{d+1})$. Let $\bar{x} := (x_1+\cdots+x_{d+1})/(d+1) = $ the average of these points. Is it true that there exists a set of $d+1$ points of distinct colors, such that $\bar{x}$ is in their convex hull?

Note that the Bárány's theorem is implied by this claim.

<sup>The motivation comes from this paper: https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00493-019-4019-y it says that a special case of Theorems 1.6 and 1.7 can be proved the the colorful Carathéodory theorem, and I wondered if the general case could be proved by a generalization of it.</sup>

Comment: The answer seems trivially true, since $\bar{x}$ is in the convex hull of the points $x_1, \dots, x_{n+1}$ and they have distinct colors. The question might be more interesting if the assumption was weakened to $x_i \in \mathrm{conv}(X_i)$.

Comment: In such a case there would be a counterexample in the plane, for example: $X_1=(0,0), X_2=(0,1), X_3=\{(10,0),(10,10)\}$.

Comment: @JanKyncl Indeed this is what I meant. Thanks for the counter-example

Comment: An even simpler example is $X_1 = X_2 = \{(0,0)\}$ and $X_3 = \{(-3,3),(3,3)\}$. Taking $x_1=x_2 =(0,0)$ and $x_3 = (0,3)$ gives $\bar{x} = (0,1)$, but for any selection of 3 points of different colors, their convex hull is an $45^{\circ}$ line that does not cross $(0,1)$.

Comment: I tried to avoid degeneracies and find an example in general position. I got an inspiration from the following paper, which may be relevant: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.comgeo.2012.01.006

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a counterexample in the plane, for example the following four points in convex position: $X_1=(0,0), X_2=(0,1), X_3=\{(10,0),(10,10)\}$.

(This was originally posted as a comment to a previous version of the question).